# Malformed ORC file error

Tags: hadoop, hive

Upon upgrading Hive External table from RC to ORC format and running MSCK REPAIR TABLE on it when I do select all from the table , I get following error -

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Malformed ORC file hdfs://myServer:port/my_table/prtn_date=yyyymm/part-m-00000__xxxxxxxxxxxxx Invalid postscript length 1
```

What is the process to be followed for migrating RC formatted historical data to ORC formatted new definition for same table if there is one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hive doesn't automatically reformat the data when you add partitions. You have two choices:

1. Leave the old partitions as RC files and make the new partitions ORC.
2. Move the data to a staging table and use insert overwrite to re-write the data as ORC files.

Answer (score -2):

> Blockquote

Add Row format ,input format and outformat to solve the problen in create statement:

create external table xyz
(
a string,
b string)
 PARTITIONED BY (
  c string)

ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat'

Loacation "hdfs path";